# rails namespace form does not write data to database

Tags: ruby-on-rails, ruby, database, forms, namespaces

i´m new to rails and like to know why my form does not write the data to the database?
if i show the data in the controller like

```
render text: params[:post].inspect
```

it is showing me the correct details. if i send the form to the database is showing just a new id and the created_at and updated_at data.

maybe there is someone who can help me...

here are my files:

LOG:

```
tarted POST "/manage/rooms" for 127.0.0.1 at 2014-03-12 09:45:28 +0100
Processing by Manage::RoomsController#create as HTML
Parameters: {"utf8"=>"✓","authenticity_token"=>"7IrPpFfkK4Krc4u6YYpUcaCp+",
"rooms"=>{"number_of_rooms"=>"1", "occupancy"=>"1", "room_type"=>"Private Room",
"gender"=>"mixed", "title"=>"foo"}, "commit"=>"Save Rooms"} (0.2ms)  BEGIN
SQL (0.4ms)  INSERT INTO "rooms" ("created_at", "updated_at") VALUES ($1, $2) 
RETURNING "id"  [["created_at", Wed, 12 Mar 2014 08:45:28 UTC +00:00],
["updated_at", Wed, 12 Mar 2014 08:45:28 UTC +00:00]] (660.8ms)  COMMIT
Redirected to http://localhost:3000/manage/rooms/27
Completed 302 Found in 664ms (ActiveRecord: 661.3ms)
```

controller: ( controllers/manage/room_cont...)

```
class Manage::RoomsController < ApplicationController

def new
end

def create
  #render text: params[:rooms].inspect
  @room = Room.new(params[:room])
  @room.save
  redirect_to [:manage, @room]
end

def show
  @room = Room.find(params[:id])
end

private
  def room_params
  params.require(:room).permit(:number_of_rooms, :occupancy, :room_type, :gender, :title)
  end
end
```

model: (models/room.rb )

```
 class Room < ActiveRecord::Base
 end
```

form: ( /views/manage/rooms/form.html... )

```
<%= simple_form_for [:manage, @room], manage_room_path do |f| %>
<p>
<%= f.input :number_of_rooms, collection: 1..20, :include_blank => false %>
</p>
<p>
<%= f.input :occupancy, collection: 1..20, :include_blank => false %>
</p>
<p>
<%= f.input :room_type, collection: ["Private Room", "Shared Room (Dorm)"],:include_blank => false %>
</p>
<p>
<%= f.input :gender, collection: ["mixed", "male", "female"], :include_blank => false %>
</p>
<P>
<%= f.label :title %><br>
<%= f.text_field :title %>
</p>
<p>
<%= f.submit %>
</p>
<% end %>
```

routes:

```
manage_rooms GET    /manage/rooms(.:format)            manage/rooms#index
                     POST   /manage/rooms(.:format)            manage/rooms#create
     new_manage_room GET    /manage/rooms/new(.:format)        manage/rooms#new
    edit_manage_room GET    /manage/rooms/:id/edit(.:format)   manage/rooms#edit
         manage_room GET    /manage/rooms/:id(.:format)        manage/rooms#show
                     PATCH  /manage/rooms/:id(.:format)        manage/rooms#update
                     PUT    /manage/rooms/:id(.:format)        manage/rooms#update
                     DELETE /manage/rooms/:id(.:format)        manage/rooms#destroy
```

Thanks!

Comment: you receive `params[:rooms]` in your controller and you use `params[:room]`

Comment: thanks. so if i understand it right. i just have to change the controller to:

     @room = Room.new(params[:rooms])

but then i do get an error like:

ActiveModel::ForbiddenAttributesError

did i miss something?

Comment: see strong parameters

Answer (score 0, accepted):

In your create action:

```
@room = Room.new(room_params)
```

and in your `room_params` method, do: `params.require(:rooms).permit...`